# Using two version of jQuery at the same time but it's causing conflicts

Tags: jquery

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#textfield2").autocomplete("location.php", {
        width: 200,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: true,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: false,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });
});

   jQuery(function(){

                jQuery("#textfield4").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter the Required field"
                });
                                jQuery("#textfield5").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter a valid Password"
                });
                jQuery("#textfield6").validate({
                    expression: "if ((VAL == jQuery('#textfield5').val()) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "password field doesn't match "
                });
                jQuery("#textfield7").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter the Required field"
                });
                jQuery("#textfield8").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter the Required field"
                });
                jQuery("#state1").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please make a selection"
                });
                jQuery("#select4").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please make a selection"
                });
                jQuery("#textfield9").validate({
                     expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[9][0-9]{9}$/)) return true; else return false;",
                     message: "Please enter a valid number"
                });  
                jQuery("#exp1").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please Select Experience"
                });
                jQuery("#jobarea").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please Select Functional Area"
                });
                jQuery("#skill").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please Enter Skills"
                });
                jQuery("#edu").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please select Education"
                });
                jQuery("#textfield10").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please Enter Resume Heading"
                });
});
```

Comment: My only question really is, why?!

Comment: Why would you use 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: Just remove smaller version. Use [jQuery migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/) if needed

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to resolve the confliction:

```
var jQ = jQuery.conflict();
```

And use the instance jQ at the replacement of `$` and `jQuery`.

**EDITED:**

After adding the above line at the top of JS use the object of that like it.:

```
jQ().ready(function() { //replace $ with jQ
    jQ("#textfield2").autocomplete("location.php", {
        width: 200,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
     jQ(function(){ //replace jQUery with jQ

            jQ("#textfield4").validate({
                expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter the Required field"
            });
      });
```

Here I have replace the `$` and `jQUery` both with the our object `jQ`.

Comment: hi expert sir canyou give me please suitable example of this problem because i am new in his field.

Comment: @user2496915 ok, I have modified my answer check that. and also accept this answer so that other SO user will get the benefit with this answer.

Comment: sir after using your valuable hint i have seen the problem that this is not working and it is due to librrary so i will show library who i am using for plugins

Comment: for autocomplete i am using

Comment: @user2496915 yah sure show me the library.

Comment: for autocomplete  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>   var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();  </script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
for validation        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="javascripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="javascripts/jquery.validation.functions.js" type="text/javascript" >
        </script>
so which jquery i am using or not.

Comment: use this code: <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script> <script src="javascripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> <script src="javascripts/jquery.validation.functions.js" type="text/javascript" > </script> ... remove older version and use new version. and add the new version on the top.

Comment: @user2496915 yes say I am here.

Comment: sir can you give me suitable example with labraray because now the login not running and i am so nedd it.

Comment: @user2496915 so you need only the autocomplete. Is your login process thru the jQUery?

Comment: i need autocomplete with vlaidation jquery form

Comment: I will give you the example after creating a demo file or code.

Comment: sir i will waiting for your response